# Why can't I call this value in a hashmap via a string key?

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

Really simple code... doesnt work and I dont know why :)

```
String appserver="";
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.put("APPSERVER101", "node101");
hm.put("APPSERVER103", "node102");
hm.put("APPSERVER105", "node103");
hm.put("APPSERVER107", "node104");
hm.put("APPSERVER201", "node108");
hm.put("APPSERVER203", "node110");

...

appserver = rs_g.getString("APPSERVER");

...

out.println("<tr><td class=\"good\">" + hm.get(appserver) + "</td>");
```

The result is NULL, but if I set it manually like:

```
out.println("<tr><td class=\"good\">" + hm.get("APPSERVER101") + "</td>");
```

I get the right result

Comment: What does `rs_g.getString("APPSERVER")` do?

Comment: can you trace the result of `appserver = rs_g.getString("APPSERVER");`?

Comment: The elephant in the room: does appserver == "APPSERVER101"?

Comment: Is it really the same?

Comment: @Bathsheba `==` is not important here, `equals()` is enough. Try with `hm.get(new String("APPSERVER101"))` : the result is `"node101"`, not `null`.

Comment: Yes appserver == "APPSERVER101" as proven by an out.println(appserver).

Comment: @thegrinner its a result from a db query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the trim with `hm.get(appserver)` to be sure that there are no extra spaces causing the problem. Also try to print the value of `appserver` variable to be sure it contains `"APPSERVER101"` and nothing else.

Comment: yeah - i already verified by printing that that value is APPSERVER101, will try a trim now

Comment: yup.... doh! whitespace is there somewhere (though I cant see it with the naked eye on the page when printing!) .... but the trim works

Answer (score 0):

`rs_g.getString("APPSERVER");` must not be returning the value `"APPSERVER101"`, otherwise the  expresssions `hm.get(appserver)` and `hm.get("APPSERVER101")` would be return the same result.

All that's happening inside the get method is a comparison of the passed value to every key in the map. If there's no match between that value and any key, that's going to be because the passed value isn't the same as as any key as judged by the .equals() method (in the case of Strings)